# Function call exiting a select box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm try to call a function when a user exits a drop down select box using `onBlur` but I can't get it to work. Here is the code.

```
    <div class="row">
<label for="CountyTab" Id="CountyText" onMouseOver=style.color="#0050FF" onMouseOut=style.color="#C0C0C0"><div class="left label">
County:</div></label><div class="left content">
<select>
           <option value="">Choose one</option>
           <option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
           <option value="Westmeath">Westmeath</option>
           <option value="Wexford">Wexford</option>
           <option value="Wicklow">Wicklow</option> id="CountyTab" onblur="countyCheck()"  
</select><div style="clear: both"></div></br>
```

Comment: What's it meant to do that it's not doing? Also, your HTML is malformed, the `id=...` string should be *inside* an HTML-element tag, not floating around as text. And, I *think*, the `blur`/`onblur` event should be in the `select`, not the `option`.

Comment: There is no onBlur, only the change event

Comment: Put onBlur inside Select Tag. working now.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as correct if it answered your question, for anyone looking for similar answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. First, your HTML, as @David said, seems malformed. Try not using inline Javascript and CSS. This is never good for your application/website. Use the below HTML as a guide:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <label for="CountyTab" class="label">County: </label>
    <select id="CountyTab">
       <option value="">Choose one</option>
       <option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
       <option value="Westmeath">Westmeath</option>
       <option value="Wexford">Wexford</option>
       <option value="Wicklow">Wicklow</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

As for the second bit of the HTML, try not using additional elements for clearfix. We have pure CSS tricks for dealing with clearing floats. Additional elements are not good for semantic.

```
label { color: #c0c0c0; }
label:hover { color: #0050ff; }

.row { padding-left: 26%; position: relative; }
.row .label { left: 0; position: absolute; width: 25%; }

/* Add the class "clearfix" to any element in your HTML is equal to adding <div style="clear: both;"></div> below that element */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

NOW to answer your original question, as @adeneo said, use the `change` event. See the code below:

```
document.getElementById("CountyTab").onchange = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.value);
}
```

The above attaches the `change` event to the element with the ID "CountyTab." Whenever the value of that element changes, the event gets fired. The function on the right side of that statement then gets called, which takes the event as a parameter. That specific code will alert the selected values of the select element.

Please see the jsfiddle for all of the above in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/UNL9D/

Comment: Thanks for the CSS. I'm a bit new to this stuff. Got the onblur working by putting it inside the opening select tag. Nice One